# Creating new column by extracting value from existing column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas

I have a df_a below that has text values in a column as below,

```
ID   | Comment              
2     @thomas what do you mean?
3     @Rob yes
4     @carol @3423 no way 
45    @13121 @Mike yes sir
```

How can I create a new column that has the name that comes after the @ sign in the comment column? I only want to create the column if that name exists in my other df called df_b with column_name as below:

df_b:

```
column_name
Mike
Rob
thomas
carol
```

expected output:

```
ID   |         Comment               | name
    2     @thomas what do you mean?    thomas
    3     @Rob yes                     Rob
    4     @carol @3423 no way          carol
    45    @13121 @Mike yes sir         mike
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using Regex `str.extract(r"@([A-Za-z]+)")`.

**Ex:**

```
df['name'] = df['Comment'].str.extract(r"@([A-Za-z]+)")
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                     Comment    name
0  @thomas what do you mean?  thomas
1                   @Rob yes     Rob
2        @carol @3423 no way   carol
3       @13121 @Mike yes sir    Mike
```

Answer (score 1):

Extract string immediately to the left of `@` written as `(?<=y)x`
where `y` =special character @- `\@`
`x`  = any alphabets a-z both lower and upper case `[A-Za-z]`

```
df['name']=df.comment.str.extract('((?<=\@)[A-Za-z]+)')



         comment              name
0  @thomas what do you mean?  thomas
1                  @Rob yes      Rob
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know that your strings will always start with `@name` followed by a space, you can do `s.split(' ')[0]` to get all the text to the left of the first space from a string `s`, and cut off the first character like this: `s.split(' ')[0][1:]` If you don't know that and just want to find the first @name in the string, you could use the `str.find` function to find the first @, and the first space after it.

To get a new column with this, i would build a simply function that does the above with `lambda`, and then use `.apply`:

```
df['name'] = df['comment'].apply(lambda s: s.split(' ')[0][1:])
```

This doesn't, however, fulfill your requirement of of not having the name column if the name isn't in your other dataframe. I assume you mean you want an empty string as your entry in those cases, since you can't really have a column that's only there for some rows. You could do this directly inside the lambda function above, but a more readable way would be just to filter them out afterward:

```
df['name'][~df['name'].isin(df_b[column_name])] = ''
```

The snippet `df['name'].isin(df_b[column_name])` gives us a binary column indicating the rows where the name is in the other dataframe, so to make all the other entries blank, we negate it with `~` to get all the rows where the name is *not* in the other dataframe, and then slice `df['name']` with this new column indicating all the rows we want to erase the name from, and set them equal to the empty string `''`.